# error in including css file

Tags: php, html, css

styles.css

```
        /* Footer */

        .footer{
            background-image: url("footer.jpg");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
```

footer.php

```
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css'>

    <div class="footer"><br>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <h2 style="color:white"><b>Address</b></h2>
                    <p style="color:white">Son Of xyz</p>
                    <p style="color:white">bangalore 560040</p>
                    <p style="color:white">karnataka india </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <h2 style="color:white"><b>Contact</b></h2>
                    <p style="color:white"><b>E-mail:</b> xyz@gmail.com</p>
                    <p style="color:white"><b>Phone:</b> +91 9999999999</p>
                    <p style="color:white"><b>Fax:</b> +91 9999999999</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <h2 style="color:white"><b>Usefull Links</b></h2>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <p><a href="" style="color:white">Home</a></p>
                            <p><a href="" style="color:white">About Us</a></p>
                            <p><a href="" style="color:white">Portfolio</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-1">
                            <p><a href="" style="color:white">Products</a></p>
                            <p><a href="" style="color:white">Careers</a></p>
                            <p><a href="" style="color:white">Contact</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><hr>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-">
                    <center><p style="color:white;"><i class="fa fa-copyright" style="font-size:24px"></i> Copyright 2018 Samson Solar - All Rights Reserved</p></center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm creating a web page with .php extension, I'm trying to include the css file in the footer.php page but its not getting displayed. please can any one tell me how may i do this. The same code when used in .html file is working but is not working if I use it as .php extension.

Comment: no need to echo a css file you can link that directly

Comment: its still not working sir

Comment: do hard refresh and check ctrl + f5

Comment: Just put that `<link>` in a `<head>`

Comment: exactly as @AymDev said place that link in head and press ctrl + f5 to get that refreshed

Comment: its not working sir

Comment: Is it the only css file in the project?

Comment: yes sir @Tarek.hms

Comment: Did you check the browser's inspector to see what happens?

Comment: no sir what does browser's inspector means? @Tarek.hms

Comment: With almost all modern browsers there is a built in developer's tool called inspector.. if you are using chrome you can access it by pressing F12

Comment: First past below code in css and see result it's working
.footer{
    background-image: url("footer.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: red;
}

Comment: `<img src="<?php echo 'IMAGES/footer.php'; ?>" height="100" width="100"/>` is this correct?

Comment: What error do you get exactly?

Answer (score 0):

U may try

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='./styles.css' type='text/css'>
```

Make sure your footer.php and your style.css in the same directory.

Comment: This reads like a game of spot the difference rather than an answer. What did you change? Why should it solve the problem?

Comment: sir its working with .html but not working with .php extension

Answer (score -1):

try this:`echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css' type='text/css'>";`(without the php code, you can link css files directly from HTML)

also I am just wondering, but wouldn't tables work better for you in this situation? as I see a lot of nested div's.